# filter is not a function. Why?

Tags: angular, filter

good day!
I don't understand where my problem. Code in Angular 13
On Form have a Button with submit() procedure

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

 users: User[] = []

 constructor(
    public auth: AuthService
  ) { }


submit() {

this.auth.getByNickName(this.form.value.nickname.trim()).subscribe(
      res => {
       this.users = res
      }
    )
}
}
```

in AuthService

```
getByNickName(nickname: string): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${environment.fbDbUrl}/users.json`).pipe(
      map((users:User[]) => users.filter((user: User) => user.nickname === nickname))
    )
  }
```

Result in console: **6402 ERROR TypeError: users.filter is not a function**
Why? :-(

Comment: Looks like you are getting an object, not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you are mentioning `6402 ERROR TypeError: users.filter is not a function` tells you that `users` does not have a method called filter() attached to it.

This is probably because the result of your `http.get` method is not an array. For example, it might be an `object`, a `null` or `undefined` value.

As you are fetching a `.json`, is suspect it is an object, not an array (It would have been helpful to have a snippet of that file)

To avoid this error you could either:

- use the optional [chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (?.) that will prevent calling the filter method on `null` or `undefined` values:

```js
map((users:User[]) => users?.filter((user: User) => user.nickname === nickname))
```

- check if your value is an array with the [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method.

To solve your issue, as i don't know how what `users.json` file looks like it is hard to help but assuming it is like:

```json
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "User1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "User2"
        }
    ]
}
```

You would have to modify your `map` method to reach the `users` property like this :

```js
map((response: { users: User[] }) => response.users.filter((user: User) => user.nickname === nickname))
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! It is not an array!  I nave a Farebase datatable like this. And how can I get from it a user request by nickname?  {
"-N7f2XPTWWb6UKmyXplj": {
"email": "Snus71@gmail.com",
"nickname": "Snus71",
"password": "123456",
"returnSecureToken": true,
"techsupport": true
},
"-N7fBx5Eb4D29yzE6xqZ": {
"email": "Snus72@gmail.com"",
"nickname": "Snus72",
"password": "123456",
"returnSecureToken": true
},
"-N7fExhhIKahFpSXagwm": {
"email": "Snus73@gmail.com"",
"nickname": "Snus73@gmail.com"",
"password": "111111",
"returnSecureToken": true
}
}

Comment: To be honest, i never used firebase and i think this new question should be ask in a dedicated topic as it is not part of `filter is not a function. Why?`
See the link below :
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Also, if my answer helped you, do not forget to accept it.